# Evaluating integrals of the form $\int f(x,dx)$

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqmIGr68RCo) which showed how one could evaluate $\int x^{dx}-1$:

$$\int x^{dx}-1$$
$$=\int \left(x^{dx}-1\right)\frac{dx}{dx}$$
$$=\int \frac{x^{dx}-1}{dx}dx$$

By Riemann Integration we have

$$\int^b_a f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)\Delta x$$

Where $x_i=a+i\Delta x$ and $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$. Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Delta x=dx$. Therefore, we can rewrite the integral as

$$\int \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{x^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}dx$$

(Note that $\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{x^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}=\ln x$)

$$=\int \ln xdx$$
$$=x\ln x-x+C$$
I am wondering about what would happen if instead of integrating $x^{dx}-1$ we integrated $f(x,dx)$ for some continuous function $f$. Using the same steps it seems like we would find that $\int f(x,dx)=\int \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f(x,\Delta x)}{\Delta x}dx$. However, the proof is not very rigorous, as dividing by $dx$ (an infinitesimal) is not valid.

---

Therefore, my question is: Is it valid to say that

$$\int f(x,dx)=\int \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f(x,\Delta x)}{\Delta x}dx$$

and what would be a rigorous proof?

Comment: This kind of integral itself is very weird to define. Could you give an idea of how to define $\int f(x,dx)$? Think about how Riemann integration is defined, and the relation between that and the notation of $\int f(x)dx$ for the Riemann integral. The question. I think then, becomes that of the interchange of limit and integral. Of course, none of this was done in the video.